# how to resolve application error in node js when deploying to heroku

Tags: node.js, mern

[{
"resource": "/C:/Users/user/Desktop/KingItSol/TryHeroku/package.json",
"owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#0",
"code": "768",
"severity": 4,
"message": "Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND json.schemastore.org.",
"startLineNumber": 1,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 1,
"endColumn": 2
}]
i am trying to upload my backend which is in node js to heroku backend has been deployed successfully and saying heroku application error then i did the heroku logs where error is about bson the its package.json is not find whereas paskage.json is present there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for asking but my issue has been resolved